# How to properly read dynamodb json data (dynamodb exported data from s3) in spark where json files may have different size of data

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have DynamoDb json files. which have data like following

```
text = sqlContext.read.text('dynamodb/*')
text.take(2)
```

```
[
Row(value='{"Item”:{“View1”:{“M”:{“1596385057313":{"B":"jSWdPakZ1cm91VWdNSWd5TmhiR1VZb2JUYi83b3U="},"1596385112207":{"B":"RNkJRMElXaWxDU2djSWdPakZ1cm9mNsTmhiR1VZaitIZS83b3U="}}},"blocking":{"BOOL":false},"date":{"S":"2020-09-13"},"id":{"S":"37816"}}}'),

 Row(value='{"Item”:{“View1”:{“M”:{“1601064727986":{"B":"mRDbHdrb0hDSUM0byt2TExsb0RDTTRLWWdRSTZPb0JjZ2tLQjBadmNsTmhiR1Y2QlEwQUFJQS9HTExyazdmTUxnPT0="},"1601064741338":{"B":"nBCOUNRZ1VOTmRDbHdrb0hDSUM0byt2TExsb0RDTTRLWWdRSTZPQS9HTnJUbExmTUxnPT0=“}}},”View2”:{“M”:{“1601064618177":{"B":"gwSkNCUTAxMEtYQ1NnY0lnTGlqNjhzdVdnTUlWkdOdDh3dQ=="},"1601064728107":{"B":"SkNCUTAxMEtYQ1NnY0lnTGlqNjhzdVdnTUl6Z3BpQkFqbzZndQ=="},"1601064741411":{"B":"RFpta0gwSkNCUTAxMEtYQ1NnY0lnTGlqNjhzdVh3dQ=="}}},"blocking":{"BOOL":false},"date":{"S":"2020-09-25"},"id”:{“S”:”1123”}}}’)
]
```

As you can see data can have view1 and/or view2. Both are map which can have any number of values.Both View1 and View2 have timestamp and their byte value.
now while reading these files as json, printschema looks like following

```
json_df  = sqlContext.read.json("dynamodb/*")
json_df.printschema()
```

````
root
 |-- Item: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- View: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- M: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- 1601064618177: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- B: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- 1601064728107: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- B: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- 1601064741411: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- B: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- View1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- M: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- 1596385057313: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- B: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- 1596385112207: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- B: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- 1601064727986: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- B: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- 1601064741338: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- B: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- blocking: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- BOOL: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |-- date: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- S: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- S: string (nullable = true)```

Now when I do df.show() like following, it will put `,` for timestamp which are not in view1 or view2 for that specific record. Imagine data is being 1 gb. I would see endless `,` 


+--------------------+
|                Item|
+--------------------+
|[, [[,,, [Q2dkSVp...|
|[[[[Q2doR1lYWnZjb...|
|[, [[[Q2dkSVpIQld...|
|[, [[,,,,,, [Q2dk...|
|[, [[,,,,, [Q2dkS...|
|[, [[,,, [Q2dkSVp...|
+--------------------+
````

How can I avoid that while reading json data.